# Change EXCEL.EXE path of cmd command "start excel"

Tags: excel

The destination of the EXCEL.EXE paths of one of the user is look like this

```
C:\ProgramData\App-V\8F2E7805-FE8E-4E71-98B7-5A50895B75A4\548B561F-7950-4B8C-8DEC-80A7FE0AEC87\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
C:\Users\rental15\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\8F2E7805-FE8E-4E71-98B7-5A50895B75A4\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\8F2E7805-FE8E-4E71-98B7-5A50895B75A4\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
```

And whenever they try to run cmd `start excel "C:\New Folder\sample.xls"`, the excel doesn't open because `EXCEL.EXE` couldn't be found whatever the path the `start excel` command was using.

I've tried looking at System Environment but I couldn't find the path for `EXCEL.EXE`. Is the path of the `EXCEL.EXE` inside the registry? How can I change the `EXCEL.EXE` path of the cmd `start excel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `start excel`, windows will look at [FTYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype):

Try using: `ftype excel`

output (on my system, with excel 2013):

```
excel=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\protocolhandler.exe "%1"
```

This info is stored in the registry (see: https://superuser.com/questions/204354/how-do-i-get-ftype-assoc-to-match-windows-explorer)

```
C:\>reg query HKLM\software\classes\excel /s

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\excel
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Url:Excel Protocol
    URL Protocol    REG_SZ
    UseOriginalUrlEncoding    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\excel\DefaultIcon
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\excel\shell

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\excel\shell\open

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\excel\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\protocolhandler.exe "%1"
```

Comment: Is this inside Registry? If yes, what is the path?

Comment: added info about registry.